# Native USB debugging on ESP32 in PlatformIO without ESP-IDF toolchain?

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, platformio

I have a custom ESP32-S2-based circuit board with USB-C which does *not* have a USB-serial converter IC like a common dev board might. On this board, USB(-) is on GPIO19, and USB(+) is on GPIO20. USB works great for powering the board and for uploading firmware.

The board works well and I have access to good old-fashioned serial console via a USB-to-logic level serial interface, but it would be nice to be able to get serial out to USB along with the firmware upload (like a dev board).

I’m using PlatformIO in Visual Studio Code, and writing with arduino-esp32 rather than ESP-IDF.

I understand by [these instructions from Espressif](https://blog.espressif.com/dfu-using-the-native-usb-on-esp32-s2-for-flashing-the-firmware-b2c4af3335f1) that when using ESP-IDF I can configure log output to go to USB CDC rather than UART, and this has been done successfully on my custom board. But I would like to be able to do this without having to switch over to ESP-IDF.

I’m presuming that one of the partitions that PlatformIO is building for me is this configuration with some nice common sense defaults, but I can’t see how I might alter those defaults to do what I’m looking for.

Any thoughts or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hearing nothing here I [asked over on the GitHub project and got an excellent answer](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/discussions/7879#discussioncomment-5087606). In short, use a custom board config file with...

```
"extra_flags": [
  "-DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=1"
 ]
```

...in it. Go read the answer there, though. It's more complete than that little tidbit.